# Network adapter missing, can't connect to the internet

Tags: internet-connection, network-adapter

So i have this issue where i can't connect to the internet, and after many days of poking around, i found out that under **Device manager > Network adapters**, the network adapter is missing. How do i fix this? I am running A HP Pavilion laptop that came with windows 8, upgraded to windows 10. I don't know which model, it doesnt say anywhere. I have had this issue before, but it was fixed with a restart. A week ago i had to restart my computer ~15 for the WiFi to work and now nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network adapter (usually a mini card) may need reseating.  You didn't give an exact model so I don't know exactly how to do this.  Check and see if there are access panels under your laptop.  If you can find the network card, it's a small card with 2 to 3 small cables attached to it (those are for the antennas btw).

Remove the screw(s) locking the card down, take the card out and put it back in.  If that doesn't work, the card may be going bad.  You can find replacements fairly cheap on fleebay.  Intel Wireless N cards usually go for around ~$10 and AC cards are usually ~$15-30.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it would go that technical. I'll just bring it into repair, they'll know what do (plus i have a broken screen)